# Currency Formating with Locale in Google App Engine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, locale

I'm attempting to format currency to the US locale using google app engine with python 2.7. This is the code that I'm using:

```
    import locale
    locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'US')
    tFloatCash = 50.00
    tStringCash = locale.currency(tFloatCash)
```

This works perfectly in the interactive shell. However, I get this error on GAE itself:

```
  File "***", line 138, in post
    locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'US')
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 531, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
  Error: unsupported locale setting
```

What can I do to resolve this problem? Is there another currency formatting library that I can quickly implement to format my floats?

Comment: While I'm still interested in an answer to this, I'm going to make a rough currency formatter myself since I'm just interested in dollars. =)

Comment: I did a complete custom formatting since the conventions differ so much. I'm planning to combined 3 varibles: currency (string), price (decimal) and "extra info" if the price is something used but in an uncommen way e.g. `2 dollar per ounce`or likewise that will be difficult to ordet compared to just decimals.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google doesn't support `locale`.

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=992

Try `moneyfmt`.

http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#recipes